# How to display grid lines (without showing label) between each ticks?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart, react-chartjs

[image]

I'm using Chart.js 2 (React-chart-js 2) to display a line chart.

Does anyone have any reference to keeping the vertical gridline between each displayed label?

It seems like the vertical gridline only showing on each displayed label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the scriptable options for this, see example that hides every second label, you can adjust it to hide a bigger step if you want.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          callback: function(val, index) {
            return index % 2 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: So the way is to define a callback function for x's ticks. Work like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following configuration

```
     var config = {
                type: 'line',
                showDatapoints: true,
                legend: { position: 'top' },
                data: data,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    hoverMode: 'index',
                    stacked: false,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart Title'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                        },
                            {
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'right',
                            id: 'y-axis-2',

                            // grid line settings
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: true, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                            },
                        }],
                    }
                }
            };
```